# Saving Large Form Data $_POST or JQuery POST

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, post

I am developing a website where a user can take a quiz. A quiz has 300 questions.

So, i need to save what the user has marked in those 300 questions.

What i have done is, i have create 300 hidden input fields. When the user clicks on Submit, i send the values as an array using `JQuery POST`.

Earlier i tried to save the values using `$_POST` but that took a lot of time and users would often think that the page is not responding.

So, now i implemented `JQuery POST` submission and created a small progress bar so that the users know that something is happening.

But still some users are saying that the values are not getting stored and they are unable to save their quiz attempt.

Below is the code i am using:

```
$.post("save.php",{array:answerArray,userID:userID,quizID:quizID},
function(data,status){showResult();});
```

I think this could be browser issue because some users are using cell phones to take the quiz and their browser might not support `JQuery`.

Can anyone please suggest me an efficient and reliable way to save data.

Thanks.

Comment: What is the value of `answerArray` , How do you save data PHP side ?

Comment: "But still some users are saying that the values are not getting stored and they are unable to save their quiz attempt." is incredibly vague. If some answers are stored, and not others, that would lead me to believe there is a programming issue somewhere's else, or they're simply skipping those answers.

Comment: Also: If you're hitting limitations, I'd recommend splitting the page up. Show users 50 questions at a time, or similar, and have them hit a next button to keep going. 300 seems a lot to display on one page.

Comment: Are you certain that users answered all questions? Do `<form>` elements have `required` and unique `name` attributes?

Comment: put all your anwers in one array or make your inputs an array

Comment: One way would be to directly trigger single saves for an answer when a question is answered. Though this needs more work on the backend as the answer could get changed again

Comment: @ismail: answerArr is a string. For e.g: 1,3,0,5 which means 1 is marked for first, 3 is marked for second question, nothing is marked for third and so on.
the form cannot be required because a user can skip an answer.

Comment: @FrankerZ: i am loading all 300 questions but the users sees only 1 question at a time. Saving a few answers (50 at a time) seems like a good idea. I will check if that can be implemented

Comment: Also, can anyone share if $_POST is a more reliable method than JQuery POST? Does JQuery POST has browser limitations?